# non http streaming video for iOS devices

Tags: ios, rtsp, jwplayer, rtmp, http-streaming

I am using wowza to restream source rtsp streams to multiple types of end devices. Due to the buffering restriction with http based streaming, I cannot use it for my application. I need to use RTMP or RTSP for my restreams.

aside: HTTP packetized streams need about 3 times the key length, or 30 seconds worth of video(silver light and quicktime), so I would have to keep my source streams turned on in wowza to keep a buffer. That is not possible in my application as I must conserve bandwidth between wowza and the source streams.

From what I understand, iOS does not support RTMP. So that leaves RTSP for iOS devices.

Using something like JWPlayer for consistency would be nice, but JWplayer does not support RTSP!!

So, is there a graceful solution. Something like JWplayer that will auto server the right client player (RTSP and RTMP clients are the only ones required). Or will I have to role my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) is a good solution. It's free and compatible with the H264 way Wowza sends video to iOS

You can create your own JS HTML5 player based on VideoJS, the source code is at GitHub: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js and the license is LGPL.

Comment: the poster said that HLS was ruled out because of letancy, re-streaming is always going to have that issue. true rtspplay does use sdl , but you failed to mention the other players on that git that do not use sdl. best solution would be ffmpeg+avfoundation+audio api  which are provided. http://sol3.typepad.com/exotic_particles/ is this even relevant it was last answered in Sept but the question is 1 year old, I vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions available for rtsp streaming on iPhone.You can choose the best fit solution amond them.

1. https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RTSPPlay - This encapsulates ffmpeg using an SDL framework and might not be of much help if you are looking for standard and complete control on UIKit elements.
2. Live555 + FFMPEG - There are apps like dropcam (https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone) which did this and this might be an interesting approach to take.
3. Audio Streaming - If you are trying to stream only audio, you can also try and download medialib demos from http://www.themidnightcoders.com/download.html.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience with ffmpeg, any ffmpeg based client can play both rtsp and rtmp streams. So, search for ffmpeg in github, you can find some open source clients..